# Ag Grid : How to add common Clear button on Ag Grid Multi Filter in React?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to add common **Clear** button on Ag Grid **Multi Filter** in react ?

We should clear all filter on active filter popup using one **Clear** button.

[Unable to clear all filter using Single Clear Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Hn8.png)

I am using following code to built **Multi Filter** in React

```
filter: 'agMultiColumnFilter',
filterParams:{
  filters: [
   {
     filter: filterType,
     // filterParams:{ buttons: ['clear']}
   },
   {
     filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
     filterParams:{ buttons: ['clear']}
   },
 ],
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding following code, i am able to clear all filter of active multifilter.

```
        const countryFilterComponent = this.agParams.api.getFilterInstance(
          this.agParams.column.getColId()
        )
        countryFilterComponent && countryFilterComponent.setModel(null)
```